# What is the logout URL for adal v2.0 common?

Tags: adal

I am using the following URL to login: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...

I get the JWT token, verify it using RS256, verify the nonce, etc., and everything is working great.

But now how do I log the user out? Microsoft's documentation which is otherwise pretty decent doesn't seem to say anything about the logout URL corresponding to the above login URL.

I am looking for official information, such as a page on Microsoft site that I may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following URL to logout with the v2 endpoint.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout